# How to highlight the potential drop areas in sortable before drop?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using JQuery's Sortable (not Draggable or Droppable) and I was wondering how I could highlight the potential drop areas (using CSS) that a user has when the user has begun sorting. Something like

http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/sortables.html

but with highlighting the area in which the item can be dropped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Placeholder option to define a css class to apply to the default white space

```
  placeholder: 'someClass'
```

Demo [here](http://pastebin.me/0becdb8141815e02aad161f3ae312056)

You can also use the change event and override the inline visibility hidden that the sortable applies to the placeholder.

See quick demo [here](http://pastebin.me/06a9a44a125af2c62a301204e9cf4254)

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    change: function(event, ui) {
      ui.placeholder.css({visibility: 'visible', border : '1px solid yellow'});
    }
});
```

Comment: Both of you were helpful, but your answer was more in-depth and helpful. Thank you once again - sometimes the simplest answers are the hardest to see.

Answer (score 0):

redsquare's inline CSS style on change worked for me, but I couldn't get it to work using a custom CSS class. Updating the jQuery `placeHolder` class in the configuration caused some oddities for me.

You can use the following CSS with no other configuration updates to get the desired result. Note that the `!important` is needed on the visibility.

```
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
    border: 1px solid rgb(12,194,170);
    visibility:visible !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the class with more classes to override the inline style:

```
.ui-sortable-placeholder.ui-sortable-handle {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    visibility: visible!important;
}
```